# Puppeteer - Run 1 browser instance across multiple tests

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Across multiple `TestFixture` a new instance of chrome browser is initialized. But I want to have only 1 instance of browser and all tests can be new tabs which I think would be more performant as well.

What is the recommended approach to do this?

I [asked](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1487) on the repo but author redirected me here.

Comment: I think you should be able to use the [`OneTimeSetupAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute) to define a method to run once and do your setting up of puppeteer once. Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem, as not everyone can access external sites and the link may, if unlikely, break